# Unity - Which is more optimal persisting between scenes? `DontDestroyOnLoad` or `LoadSceneMode.Additive`

Tags: unity, c#, monobehaviour

**User [philip](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/21890/philipp) previously marked this as a duplicate question of [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110958/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-data-between-scenes), but failed to actually read either question it seems.** The question that this was marked as a duplicate of, does not address the Additive scene loading using Unity `SceneManager`.

---

Let me premise this with, this is not intended to be an "x vs y" opinion piece, I am simply looking for information on **what is more optimal** and **what is the preferred way**.

tldr;

I am new to unity and over the past week built a very small 2D 'Shooter' game to help me learn how to interact with the engine. When trying a new project and looking in to persisting game managers between scenes, I initially found the `DontDestroyOnLoad` syntax.

DontDestroyOnLoad vs LoadSceneMode

- Which is more optimal for large games/scenes?
- Both methods appear to do the same thing, except you create the scene yourself of additive scene loading.
- New to Unity looking in to methods of persisting objects and in-memory data between scenes.
- People mentioned the Unity Docs stating to not use `DontDestroyOnLoad` but I can't find this.

---

Essentially, I had the following on (at the time) two 'manager' scripts. When then calling `SceneManager.LoadScene(#);` in other parts of the code and in other scenes, these managers persisted between scenes.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MyBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

It worked, no issues there. However when looking in to other methods to ensure what I was doing is 'good practice' and 'optimal' I had come across a few places mentioning **not** to use this method, a few people mentioned that the [unity docs for DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) also reiterate this, I could not find such text. Instead, they mention having a 'Manager Scene' with all of the objects to persist being within that scene.

---

To implement this, I had to add a third manager, 'CustomSceneManager' that handles unloading the current scene and loading a new one, while persisting the current 'ManagerScene'.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class CustomSceneManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int _currentScene = -1;

    // This is in the manager scene, so the manager scene always gets pulled in to scenes
    // when a scene is switched via this method.
    public void SwitchScene(int sceneId) {
        if (_currentScene != -1) {
            SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(_currentScene);
        }
        _currentScene = sceneId;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneId, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
    }
}
```

This method also works, with the overhead of a further *empty* GameObject / Manager to handle scene logic (I would likely need this to be a manager in the future anyway as I instance parts of the game) and the fact that anywhere I switch scene, I need to go via this manager, which means finding it/creating a reference where I want to use it vs just calling Unitys built in scene manager methods.

---

Comment: Welcome to a stack exchange site. If you think that your question has been closed without a good reason, please add comment on the original question explaining why you think so, and vote for reopen. Creating a new question for the same topic is not the way to go here as it creates _more_ duplicate content, something we're trying to avoid.

Comment: @Vaillancourt Apologies, the app doesn't say as such, in fact, it says to open a new question. https://imgur.com/a/yMuAqf2

Comment: @Vaillancourt Also, I can not vote to re-open the question on this Stack Exchange due to not having the reputation. It is like you guys are intentionally driving people elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. That's an oddity and it conflicts with the [help center](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) (last paragraph); I assume this is due to the reduce space on the mobile app.

Comment: If you can't vote to reopen your own question might also be an issue. I'll try and see about it. Meanwhile you can ping a mod or the user that closed the question and try and get them to reopen the question.

Comment: I checked for the issue with the text on the mobile app, and it is being discontinued (hasn't been updated since 2017). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028). It is suggested to use the web site and enable the mobile design.

Comment: And for the reopening, it seems you're stuck with what's [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions). Note that when you edit your (closed) question, it goes into a "reopen" vote queue, so your question will be seen by others and potentially reopened.

Comment: @Vaillancourt Thanks for getting back to me on these issues, I hadn't realised the app was discontinued and will be sure to use the mobile site in the future. As for the question reopening, I will probably head over to unity answers in the meantime and ask there instead. Hope you have a good day.