# Instantiate only specific objects in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, data

Here is the situation: I have 10 weapons in my game, in main menu player may choose only two weapons that could take to the game, and this information about two weapons will save in a kind of "inventory". So the question is how I could instantiate only two objects from "inventory"?

Comment: [You might find some useful inspiration in this past Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/181498/39518), about how to change what spawns in a level based on a choice a player made in a preceding menu scene.

Comment: @DMGregory Actually I found the solution by loading from Resource folder. But thanks for the answer, I will watch it.

Comment: @Dazzi If you figured out a solution yourself, then please post an answer to your own question and accept it. That way the question no longer appears as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by loading from Resource folder.
`GameObject weaponOne = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Gun1"), this.gameObject.transform) as GameObject;`

Comment: You may want to use Addressables rather than Resources. These are a more modern solution that scale better to bigger games.

Comment: @DMGregory it's mobile project and I like your solution, so need to know more about that

Comment: And `Gun1` looks hard coded, what if the player chooses weapon 7 and 9?

Comment: @Zibelas Yes I know, this snippet is for show